# All possible combinations of a combinations of characters

Tags: random, char, combinations

I need to get every possible combination of characters that follows a rule.

Say:

Length:  5-6
Characters: ABCabc123

I should get stuff back like this:

```
AAAAA
AAAAB
AAABA
AAABB
..
..
AcbC13
```

Is there any way to do this quick an efficiently?

Please keep in mind I am using VB.net but I do understand concepts related to just general speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some good code to do exactly that here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx

Comment: Thanks so much!  I never knew it had a name :)!  I decree this question, ANSWERED!

Comment: Link broken, this is why links are not recommended without some context that provides enough insight independent of the link.